# Hiding rows in QTableWidget if 1 of the column does not have any values

Tags: python, pyqt, maya, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I had wanted some opinions about a portion of code that I have written. My UI consists of a `QTableWidget` in which it has 2 columns, where one of the 2 columns are populated with `QComboBox`.

For the first column, it will fill in the cells with the list of character rigs (full path) it finds in the scene, while the second column will creates a `Qcombobox` per cell and it populates in the color options as the option comes from a json file.

Right now I am trying to create some radio buttons that gives user the option to show all the results, or it will hides those rows if there are no color options within the `Qcombobox` for that particular row.

As you can see in my code, I am populating the data per column, and so, when I tried to put in `if not len(new_sub_name) == 0:` while it does not put in any `Qcombobox` with zero options, but how do I go about hiding such rows where there are no options in the `Qcombobox`?

```
def populate_table_data(self):
    self.sub_names, self.fullpaths = get_chars_info()

    # Output Results
    # self.sub_names : ['/character/nicholas/generic', '/character/mary/default']
    # self.fullpaths : ['|Group|character|nicholas_generic_001', '|Group|character|mary_default_001']

    # Insert fullpath into column 1
    for fullpath_index, fullpath_item in enumerate(self.fullpaths):
        new_path = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(fullpath_item)
        self.character_table.setItem(fullpath_index, 0, new_path)
        self.character_table.resizeColumnsToContents()

    # Insert colors using itempath into column 2
    for sub_index, sub_name in enumerate(self.sub_names):
        new_sub_name = read_json(sub_name)

        if not len(new_sub_name) == 0:
            self.costume_color = QtGui.QComboBox()
            self.costume_color.addItems(list(sorted(new_sub_name)))
            self.character_table.setCellWidget(sub_index, 1, self.costume_color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide rows using [setRowHidden](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#setRowHidden). As for the rest of the code, I don't see much wrong with what you currently have, but FWIW I would write it something like this (completely untested, of course):

```
def populate_table_data(self):
    self.sub_names, self.fullpaths = get_chars_info()
    items = zip(self.sub_names, self.fullpaths)
    for index, (sub_name, fullpath) in enumerate(items):
        new_path = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(fullpath)
        self.character_table.setItem(index, 0, new_path)
        new_sub_name = read_json(sub_name)
        if len(new_sub_name):
            combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
            combo.addItems(sorted(new_sub_name))
            self.character_table.setCellWidget(index, 1, combo)
        else:
            self.character_table.setRowHidden(index, True)

    self.character_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but any insights on how I am populating my data?

Comment: @dissidia. Not sure how useful it is to you, but I've expanded my answer a little bit.

Comment: I will be sure to check it out, forgotten to bring my code back home. But even so, can I ask why `(sub_name, fullpath)` being bracketed together? I guess this is simply optimizing and making my code shorter?

Comment: @dissidia. The brackets are required for tuple expansion. I forgot to put the `enumerate` in there, so that may not have been obvious.